# How to generate a working graph with highlights in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am trying to generate a graph from excel sheet where A column is speed B is distance. Value in A and B column will not change, C column will have the speed voilation and d will have the points where voilation happened.

I am trying to generate a graph speed vs distance with voilation highlighted on it.

This generates a graph but there is no information on it.

```js
document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);

document.getElementById('saveButton').addEventListener('click', saveGraph, false);

var graphCanvas = document.getElementById('graphCanvas');

var chart;

function handleFile(e) {

  var file = e.target.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {

    var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);

    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
      type: 'array'
    });

    // Assuming the data is in the first sheet

    var sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];

    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

    // Extract speed and distance values from columns A and B

    var speedValues = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
      header: 1,
      range: 'A:A'
    });

    var distanceValues = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
      header: 1,
      range: 'B:B'
    });

    // Extract violation points from column C

    var violationPoints = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
      header: 1,
      range: 'C:C'
    });

    // Create an array to hold labels and datasets for Chart.js

    var chartLabels = speedValues.map(function(value) {
      return value[0];
    });

    var chartDatasets = [

      {

        label: 'Speed & Distance',

        borderColor: 'black',

        data: speedValues.map(function(value, index) {

          return {
            x: value[0],
            y: distanceValues[index][0]
          };

        }),

        fill: false

      }

    ];

    // Add violation dataset with red line

    var violationData = [];

    violationPoints.forEach(function(point) {

      var index = chartLabels.indexOf(point[0]);

      if (index !== -1) {

        violationData.push({
          x: point[0],
          y: distanceValues[index][0]
        });

      }

    });

    if (violationData.length > 0) {

      chartDatasets.push({

        label: 'Speed Violation',

        borderColor: 'red',

        data: violationData,

        fill: false

      });

    }

    // Create the graph using Chart.js

    chart = new Chart(graphCanvas, {

      type: 'line',

      data: {

        labels: chartLabels,

        datasets: chartDatasets

      },

      options: {

        responsive: true,

        scales: {

          x: {
            display: true,
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Speed'
            }
          },

          y: {
            display: true,
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Distance'
            }
          }

        }

      }

    });

  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

}

function saveGraph() {

  graphCanvas.toBlob(function(blob) {

    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    link.download = 'graph.jpg';

    link.click();

  }, 'image/jpeg');
}
```

I have tried a normal graph that works for speed vs distance. But this highlight thing is not working.

Comment: I am unaware of the ability to use Excel from javascript - are you using a specific library or module to allow you to do that?  If so, please provide details by [edit]ing your question